# React Material UI Updating TextField Values

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I start the session like this

```
state = {
    firm: null,
    office: null,
    salesCode: null,
    account: null
}
```

I have each TextField showing like this:

```
<TableCell>
    <TextField
        id="standard-bare"
        defaultValue={items.data[i].firm}
        margin="normal"
        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, items.data[i].id)}
    />
</TableCell>
```

Then I have a handleChange event

```
handleChange({ event, id }) {
    const { data } = this.state;
    data[id] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({data})
}
```

When I run and edit the text inside TextField I get the below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
UserDataTable.handleChange:75
  72 |    
  73 |    handleChange({ event, id }) {
  74 |        const { data } = this.state;
> 75 |        data[id] = event.target.value;
     | ^  76 |        this.setState({data})
  77 |    }
  78 |
```

I am trying to implement edit function to the table. So if user edits the text, I get the new updated information and do the API call to update the values accordingly there.

Comment: It should be `handleChange(event, id) {`

Comment: now I get TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing an object to handleChange to extract but more of individual params so

Change

```
handleChange({ event, id }) {
```

To

```
 handleChange(event, id) {
```

Edit:

There is no data defined in state but you are accessing it and trying to set input value to the data object by id which isn’t correct. It should be something like below

```
     handleChange(event, id) {
        this.setState({
              [id]: event.target.value
        })
    }
```

Comment: now I get TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined error

Comment: I think it's sending id for all changes and that's a problem it needs to update whatever field I am updating right? like if I am updating firm it needs to update that specific firm's state..

Comment: I have this that is similar to what you entered handleChange({ event, id }) {
    const { data } = this.state;
    data[id] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({data})
}